# rewrite .htaccess for a link like http://DomainName.com/UserName

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to do a .htaccess rewrite, which when users enter this **http://DomainName.com/UserName** should go to **http://DomainName.com/UserDirectory/UserName**, but should show **http://DomainName.com/UserName** to the user

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule !^/([^/]*)$ /UserDirectory/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I want to place it in the respective web folder and apache should reflect once?

Comment: You need to put it in the root directory.

What does "reflect" mean in this context?